# how to check if hup signal completes its process other than log parsing?

Tags: unix, solaris

I have one process running to which i need to send HUP signal and confirm if it completes.

```
pkill HUP [process]
```

I did it currently using log file but there are many things i need to take care of..
same log file is updating 100 times with hup done message which i have to parse for latest hup done etc etc.

is there any flag set or system event set if hup fired and complete ?

has anyone doing such checks like hup signal fired on process and checks if it really completes?

thanks for reply

Comment: What do you mean by "completes its process"? It's easy to use `dtrace` to tell you when the target process is about to start executing its signal handler for SIGHUP. If you want to know when the signal handler has done certain things, that's a bit harder, and it depends what things you want to look for.

Comment: thanks for comment, actually this is demon process which is not in my control, writes logs in background, i just need to check whenever hup fires something is written in log , m parsing it and checking for hup done, is there any better way,,like any system event or flag is set when any signal send to demon ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dtrace` to watch for signals being handled by using the `proc:::signal-handle` probe. A list of similar probes can be found in [the dtrace proc provider documentation](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/DTrace/proc+Provider#procProvider-TBLPROC).

Here's an example that will watch for a `SIGHUP` being handled by a particular process ID. `dtrace` is fairly flexible, and can also watch all processes with a given name or userid.

```
# cat sig.d
proc:::signal-handle
/ pid == $1 && args[0]==SIGHUP /
{
  printf("pid %d - %s - got signal %d at %Y\n", pid, execname, args[0], walltimestamp);
}
# sleep 300 &
1054
# dtrace -q -s sig.d 1054 &
1057
# kill -HUP 1054
# pid 1054 - sleep - got signal 1 at 2014 Mar 13 10:31:03
1054 Hangup
#
```

Comment: thanks for comment, does there any flag set if hup process completes? is it depends on the process to process or any sig-handle is released after completion etc like??

Comment: @user1145280 It depends what you mean by "completes". Please give an example of what the process receiving the signal does that you'd like to monitor.

Comment: actually the thing is like there is daemon process, in order to make configuration update, I do - pkill -HUP <process> from my source and I can see in logs messages like HUP:start and after bla bla updates it says HUP:done now ...as there is no control in my hands, i can only parse the logs after firing HUP till it HUP:done .. instaed of this log parsing ..i want to know if anything else can be done..? like u said signal stuff etc.

Comment: @user1145280 Do you want something that can tell you when the daemon process writes anything to the log file?